# IE10 Hover Menu Display

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

Just upgraded my IE to version 10 on Windows 7 yesterday, and am having problems with hover menus.

Seems to work fine on other browsers I've tried(including previous versions of IE) but on IE10 the popup table menu loses background and border.  At first on page load it is ok but on moving across items loses the table background color and border(appears table becomes 0 width for some reason).

Here is some sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IE 10 Menu Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        li {
            background-color: #cccccc;
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            width: 80px;
        }
        li table {
            background-color: #cccccc;
            border: 1px solid #999999;
            display: none;
            left: 75px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 1000;
        }
        li:hover table {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Fish
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>Cod</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Salmon</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </li>
            <li>Fruits
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>Apple</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Orange</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </li>
            <li>Grains
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>Rice</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Wheat</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </li>
            <li>Meat
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>Beef</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Chicken</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </li>
            <li>Vegetables
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>Carrot</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Tomato</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

IE Version: 10.0.9200.16521

Thanks for any help!

*Edit: have added jsfiddle of example above here for people to try out: http://jsfiddle.net/3Babs/*

*Edit 2: Added screenshot images from different browsers to compare:

1. Chrome (25.0.1364.172)
   [image: Chrome]
2. Firefox (19.0.2)
   [image: Firefox]
3. IE10 (10.0.9200.16521)
   [image: IE10]
4. Opera (11.64)
   [image: Opera]

Answer (score 0):

This should work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/ESd8y/1/

Remove the background colour from the table and add it to the `tr` instead. You will see gaps due to borders not collapsing in tables, so you need to collapse them:

```
li table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        /* other styles here, except background-color */
    }
li table tr {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Once you make these changes it should work as expected.