# BG image mouseover working fine, exept on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hover, mouseover

Hope you can help me :-)

My html code i working fine in Google Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE10.
Can anyone see what is wrong in the code?

My site:
http://produkt-guiden.dk/testside2

My code:

```
<style type="text/css">
#cell1 {
  width: 610px;
  height: 1000px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-image: url(/media/wysiwyg/guiden1.png)
}
#cell1:hover {
  background-image: url(/media/wysiwyg/guiden0.png)
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td id="cell1"><iframe src="myiframeurlcode" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" allowtransparency="true" width="610px" height="1500px">iframe not supported!</iframe></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IE10 has issues with background-color/image with hovers [(discussed here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400548/ie10-hover-menu-display). I would suggest use JavaScript to add/remove a class by name "hover" on mouseenter and mouseleave. In css change

```
 #cell1:hover {
  background-image: url(/media/wysiwyg/guiden0.png)
 }
```

to

```
 #cell1.hover {
  background-image: url(/media/wysiwyg/guiden0.png)
 }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply :)
What JavaScript do you suggest i have to use?

Is not working to change my css code from a : to .

Comment: `$('#cell1').hover(function(){$(this).addClass('hover')},function(){$(this).removeClass('hover')})` this would do, if you are using jquery